# ZeroMQ + NodeJs: Messages not received by subscriber

Tags: javascript, node.js, message, zeromq, publish-subscribe

My publisher (`zpub.js`) publishes in a loop as shown below.

```js
async function publishLoop() {
    let payload = []
    _.forEach(array, (a) => {
       // process a here to generate someKey and someValue
       payload.push({someKey:someValue})
    })

  return Promise.all(payload.map(async (p) => {
    await zmqp.publish({t:'topicString', m:p})
  }))
}
```

`zmqp.publish` is simply the following.

```js
async publish(payload) {
    // this.sock is just a bind to tcp://127.0.0.1:4030
    await this.sock.send([payload.t, JSON.stringify(payload.m, null, null)])
    return Promise.resolve()
}
```

My subscriber (`zsub.js`) is a version of code as seen on the ZeroMQ website.

```js
const zmq = require("zeromq")
const mom = require('moment-timezone')

async function run() {
  const sock = new zmq.Subscriber

  sock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4030")
  sock.subscribe("topicString")

  for await (const [topic, msg] of sock) {
    console.log(`${mom().tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS')}`)
  }
}

run()
```

1. I start my subscriber as `node zsub.js > out`.
2. I launch my publisher as `node zpub.js`. All messages received successfully.
3. The `zpub.js` process ends but `zsub.js` keeps running. When I re-run `node zpub.js`, **not a single message** is received by the subscriber. The number of records in `out` remains unchanged.
4. Running `zpub.js` once or twice again seems to deliver messages (the recent ones; not the earlier ones as seen by timestamp) to subscriber.

Thus, I am not sure, what is to be done on the pub/sub side so that messages aren't 'lost'. Please advise.

Comment: "running zpub.js once or twice again seems to deliver messages". I don't think communication is restored because of restarting a few times but because enough time has passed. What happens when you wait "a long enough time" between stopping and restarting your publisher once?

Comment: Of course. :) Waiting long enough seems to work well.

Comment: I ran the tests again. Average of 90 publications per `node zpub.js` with 20 seconds gap and messages are getting dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pub-Sub is inherently unreliable because there is no feedback from the subscribers to the publisher to acknowledge that messages have been received. [The guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter5#Pros-and-Cons-of-Pub-Sub) describes this in detail and provides some solutions. One of the solutions is not to use Pub-Sub but, for example Router-Dealer. It depends on your use-case whether this is a viable alternative.

Regarding your specific issue, the subscriber eventually determines that the connection to the publisher is lost and will try to reconnect until a connection is re-established. Depending on the timing, the subscriber can miss initial (or all) messages send by the publisher.

In general, Pub-Sub works best if the publisher is the stable part of the communication (stays up and online, like a server) and the subscribers can come and go (like a client).

Comment: "Pub-Sub works best if the publisher is the stable part of the communication (stays up and online, like a server) and the subscribers can come and go (like a client)."  This is key...thanks!